# Dependency injection in WebApiConfig class

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ninject

Can I Inject an instance of a class using Ninject in WebApiConfig class of a Asp.net Web Api project?
This is my attempt

```
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {    
        private static IAccountsService _accountsService;

        [Inject]
        public static IAccountsService AccountsService 
        {
            get { return _accountsService; }
            set { _accountsService = value; }
        }

        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var authentication = CreateAuthenticationConfiguration();
            config.MessageHandlers.Add(new AuthenticationHandler(authentication));

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        }

        private static AuthenticationConfiguration CreateAuthenticationConfiguration()
        {
            var authentication = new AuthenticationConfiguration
            {
                RequireSsl = false,
                EnableSessionToken = true
            };

            // Basic Authentication
            authentication.AddBasicAuthentication(AccountsService.ValidateAccountUsingSiteCredential);

            return authentication;
        }
    }
```

However, I am getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` on this line `authentication.AddBasicAuthentication(AccountsService.Validate);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using something similar to the following in our global.asax to inject dependencies.

```
DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<WebApiConfig>()
     .Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

Edit: Forgot to mention that our `WebApiConfig` class is not static.

Comment: I added that to `Application_Start` and removed static from the  class and the methods in `WebApiConfig`. Now, ninject seems to be working now. But the Web Api routes don't seem to be registering at all. I am getting `404` for everything. Do we have do anything else for the routes?

Comment: I had to add `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<WebApiConfig>().Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);` to the top of `Application_Start`, that fixed routing.

Comment: Also, instead of setter injection I did constructor injection.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things which could help you

1) Use the Ninject.Web.Common package which runs the following methods

[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

As you can see **PreApplicationStartMethod** runs before AppStart and when you add the "Ninject.Web.Common", there will be a guide on how you need to WireUp your Services.

2) I usually prefer to Implement an Interface called **INeedInitialization** which has a method call **Initialize(IKernel ninjectKernel)**

This way I can dynamically locate all implementations at run-time and pass the instance of Ninject's StandardKernel and perform the Binding in a plug and play manner.

3) Expose the IKernal instance from the NinjectWebCommon as "**KernelInstance"**
after all modules have been loaded

4) You can use the following to Bind "**YourMessageHandler**" to itself
kernel.Bind().ToSelf().InSingletonScope() in one of your implementations of "**INeedInitialization"** or wherever you have your Binding logic.
All dependencies can be injected via constructor injection in .

5) Register **"YourMessageHandler"** handler like this config.MessageHandlers.Add(NinjectWebCommon.KernelInstance.Get<**YourMessageHandler**>());

6) Fire up your application and let NInject do its magic